# galaxy tab video conference

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, video-conference

I'm confused... the Galaxy Tab commercials make a special point of showing people doing video conferencing on the device, and yet, I have been entirely unable to evoke said functionality from the one I have in my hands here (it's with Verizon)... So... what gives?!

Comment: As matt read expressed it would be helpful if you explained what you've tried.

Comment: I *tried Skype and then looked around for anything else that would suggest video conferencing... I mean... how much searching am I expected to do, given the amount of time Verizon has dedicated to promoting this feature in their advertising, one would imagine I wouldn't have to do a whole lot!

Comment: You're putting too much faith in truth in advertising. Supposedly its possible, and big red implies that its easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you "evoking" this functionality? Video conferences do no appear from the ether. Try a video conferencing app, perhaps -- like Qik, Fring, or Yahoo! Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

There have been reported problems with qik on the galaxy tab, particularly no option to start a chat. Try to download something from vcast apps or try oovoo. Sorry for not giving any links but I'm on my droid and my latest CM update is acting crazy closing my browser w/o warning.

Comment: Don't see anything on vcast apps that would do this.  Do you know of something in particular?  oovoo yields no results in market.

Comment: I don't know anything in particular I just read somewhere that there were some different apps.  For oovoo search google.